# Data frame formation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-processing

I need to create a data frame for 100 customer_id along with their expenses for each day starting from 1st June 2019 to 31st August 2019. I have customer id already in a list and dates as well in a list. How to make a data frame in the format shown.

```
CustomerID  TrxnDate

1        1-Jun-19
1        2-Jun-19
1        3-Jun-19
1        Upto....
1        31-Aug-19
2        1-Jun-19
2        2-Jun-19
2        3-Jun-19
2        Upto....
2        31-Aug-19
and so on for other 100 customer id
```

I already have customer_id data frame using pandas function now i need to map each customer_id with the date ie assume we have customer id as 1 then 1 should have all dates from 1st June 2019 to 31 aug 2019 and then customerId 2 should have the same dates. Please see the data frame required.

Comment: Please, provide a sample of your data. That helps to reproduce it. Thanks !

Comment: Without seeing how your input data looks like, nothing can't be suggested

Comment: my data is same shown above. I have customer_id=[1,2,3,4,5...100] and dates=[1 Jun 2019, 2 Jun 2019...... 31 Aug 2019]. Now i need the data frame for plotting graph using this data frame. Please help @AlexandreB.

Answer (score 1):

```
# import module
import pandas as pd 

# list of dates
lst = ['1-Jun-19', '2-Jun-19', ' 3-Jun-19'] 


# Calling DataFrame constructor on list 
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Repeat the operations for Customer ID and store in df2 or something and then

```
frames = [df, df2]

result = pd.concat(frames)
```

There are simpler methods , but this will give you a idea how it is carried out.
I see you want specific dataframes, so first creat the dataframes according to customer ID 1. then repeat same for Customer ID 2, and then concat those dataframes.